# How to style the content of an iframe from parent <div>

Tags: jquery, iframe, modal-dialog

I have 3 pages. Page1 (on button click) calls page2 through a modal (modal1). Page2 has button when clicked opens page3 through a modal(modal2). So its modal inside another modal.

I don't want to kill/close the parent modal. But instead adjust css(top, left) of modal2.

How do I do this?

Here is how the overall structure looks:

```
<div id="preferences" class="modal bigModal in" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="false">
    <iframe id="preference" class="searchModal-body" src="preferences?lightbox=yes&section=2">
         <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
             <div id="searchBox" class="modal bigModal in" aria-hidden="false">
                 ..........
             </div>
            ....
         </html>
         .........
     </iframe>
     ...........
</div>
```

Attached the screenshot of how it looks now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#preference').contents().find("#searchBox").offset({top:10, left:30});
```

But browser security will allow such manipulations if iframe is from the same domain

Comment: Is $('#preference').contents().length > 0 and $('#preference').contents().find("#searchBox").length > 0 ?

Comment: Did you changed searchBox's css position to absolute to made offset changing make sence?